# Java -- reading in hexadecimal numbers using a scanner

Tags: java, user-input, hex, java.util.scanner

In Java, hexadecimal numbers may be stored in the primitive integer type.

```
private static volatile final synchronized int x = 0x2FE;
```

However reading in a hex using the Scanner class's `nextInt()` method throws an input mismatch exception. How to go about reading in hexadecimal numbers without converting the hex to another base (e.g. two or ten or whatever). THANKS.

EDIT:

This code is throwing the same exceptions. What am I doing wrong here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //scan.useRadix(16);
        int[] input = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            //input[i] = scan.nextInt(16);
            System.out.println(input[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what that line of code does. It doesn't "store hex" ... it's stores an int that you specified in hex.

Comment: No, I get it. hex is a representation of an integer. And I want the scanner.nextInt() to recognize hexadecimal as a valid representation of an integer. After the x=0x2FE statement is executed, x will store a decimal number (240 of whatever), or binary, rather, but it will be displayed as decimal.

Comment: I uncommented out the `input[i] = scan.nextInt(16);` line and just ran your code and it worked fine, with no exceptions.  Post the exception trace you're getting.

Comment: Don't type `0x` in front of your input. I suspect this is the problem. Just type `2FE`

Comment: Yeah I was putting the 0x. Sometimes I can be remarkable dense. Thanks all.

Comment: To elaborate on what Brian said -- the `0x` in a source code literal is to tell the compiler that the literal is being expressed in hex.  That's not needed here because by passing in `16` to the `nextInt()` method you're telling it you'll be sending hex at it.  And hex is just the characters 0 to 9 and A to F (or a to f).  So the `x` will make it die.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scanner class has this:
`public int nextInt(int radix)`

If you put `16` as the radix, it will probably do what you want to do.

Comment: @farm - this is the correct answer, and it will parse the string containing the hex representation of the int into an int.

Comment: What do you mean, "Nah"?  His suggestion does exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you do this:

```
int value1 = 0x2FE;
int value2 = new Scanner("2FE").nextInt(16);
```

Both `value1` and `value2` will be integer 766 in base 10.